# Modify objects returned by Mongoose

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model

I've been looking into Mongoose docs and I can't find a way to achieve what I would want to do. 
Consider a MongoDB Users collection. 
Also consider a Mongoose UserSchema which has all the fields found in the DB collection.

Now, I'd like to log to the console, all the users, but with changed properties. Sort of doing like:

```
Users = mongoose.UserSchema;
ApiUserSchema;    
Users.find(function(err,users){
    //for each user that mongoose finds, 
    //I want to convert from UserSchema to "ApiUserSchema"
    //Something like the following:
    newUsers = users.ToApiUserSchema();
    console.log(newUsers);
})
```

users.ToApiUserSchema():

```
function toApiUserSchema(user){
     username = user.username;
     email = user.email;
     someAggregate = user.Username + user.Email;
     .......and so on.....;
}
```

Given the async type of the .find() function I'm not sure if this can be done. I come from C# and PHP background, only worked with relational databases and this would be easily accomplished by having a function in the User class that just returns the wanted values.

Can it be done?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create static method for this on user Schema. Its important that you define static method between schema and model creation. Also note that `find` returns array not one object.

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: Number
})

userSchema.statics.toApiUserSchema = function(data) {
    return data.map(function(user) {
        return {
            email: user.email,
            username: user.username,
            emailAndUsername: user.email + user.username
        }
    })
}

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    console.log(User.toApiUserSchema(users))
})
```

Comment: You are the God I've been waiting for this whole day. Thanks!